# Opening image in ERDAS Imagine

Tags: erdas-imagine

I am trying to open a .img image fil in ERDAS Imagine and I keep getting the message "End of file reading dictionary" with ERDAS not responding. The program gets stuck here and I have to shut it down. How can I view the image?

Comment: Can any other application read the file?  It's far more likely that the file is corrupt than anything is wrong with Imagine.

Comment: There's a file along with it that opens perfectly...Plus other class members have been able to view the image.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the type of image? size? source?  What version of imagine?

Comment: Also, the location. Is it the same file that others are reading, as from a network share, or does each workstation have a unique copy? Have you tried generating an `md5sum` or `shasum` from multiple hosts?

Comment: It's a .img image coupled with a .rrg. ERDAS Imagine 2014. Each workstation has a unique copy. It almost seems like the whole image isn't downloading.

Comment: Please update the question with these details.  You should find a data integrity tool like the two sum tools mentioned above. I expect one of the two files is different that the files on the working hosts.